# find string by compare to values

Tags: php

I'm using a web-service to get products details.
I want to compare two values and, if they are equal, to print "FOUND".
For some reason I get nothing.

The problem is with the last IF:

```
if ($product['ProductId'] ==  $paxServices['ProductId'])
```

This is the output:

```
paxProID:332 ?? pro:-1
paxProID:332 ?? pro:332
paxProID:332 ?? pro:6
paxProID:6 ?? pro:-1
paxProID:6 ?? pro:332
paxProID:6 ?? pro:6
```

As you can see, there are 2 equal numbers: 332 (second row) and 6 (the last row)

The PHP code:

```
foreach ($pnrPaxsXml AS $i => $pax)
{
    if ($pax['ID'] == $_GET['paxID'])
    {
        foreach ($pax->Order AS $i => $paxServices)
        { 
            foreach ($pnrProductsXml AS $i => $product)
            {   
                echo "paxProID:".$paxServices['ProductId']."<>pro:".$product['ProductId']."<br />" ;

                if ($product['ProductId'] ==  $paxServices['ProductId'])
                    echo "FOUND<br />";
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the code in this way

```
if (intval($product['ProductId']) ===  intval($paxServices['ProductId']))
                echo "FOUND<br />";
        }
```

Comment: this means that the condition also check if the values have the same type. i'm using only  "==" so I'm just check if the value is the same, and thats mean less conditions...

Comment: you are just converting both into int type so that you are able to compare